# What clang-format options control format of method calling parameters?

Tags: objective-c, formatting, clang, clang-format

I know people have different opinions on how to format method calls in Objective-C, i.e.

```
[self presentViewController:scanViewController
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

vs

```
[self presentViewController:scanViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What options in my .clang-format file do I use to control this indenting? (If I don't want it, colons to line up, etc)

Also, is it just me or is this formatter ignorant of blocks? Notice how the if statement for the success block is not indented, nor is the NSLog function in the failure block.

```
[self.client getPath:path
    parameters:parameters
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    if ([from_id isEqualToString:self.from_id]) {
        self.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseObject];
    }
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(error.description);
    }];
```

Comment: I've decided to go with uncrustify instead.

Comment: Being unable to disable colon-alignment is the only thing that bothers me in clang-format. Or, better yet, disabling colon alignment in methods with block parameters.

Comment: @user3099609, if you still need solution for this issue check my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

I looked into the clang-format source code where the formatting of objective-c method expressions is done and found it here: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Format/ContinuationIndenter.cpp

The code:

```
// If this '[' opens an ObjC call, determine whether all parameters fit
// into one line and put one per line if they don't.
if (Current.Type == TT_ObjCMethodExpr &&
    getLengthToMatchingParen(Current) + State.Column >
        getColumnLimit(State))
  BreakBeforeParameter = true;
```

As you can see the behavior is only controlled by the configuration option ColumnLimit. You could set it to 0 to suppress the line breaks. Unfortunately this has, of course, impact on the complete formatting.

Regarding the problem with the missing indention within blocks: I could not reproduce that with the latest Visual Studio Plugin (SVN r203967). Have you perhaps fiddled with ContinuationIndentWidth?

Comment: I already have my ColumnLimit set to 0 and I'm using Xcode with a plugin to format on save using the .clang-format file.

Comment: Oh, setting ColumnLimit to 0 doesn't work. You have to set ColumnLimit to something very big like 1000 to avoid line breaks in method expression. Regarding your second problem, what is the content of your .clang-format and which version of clang-format do you use?

Comment: Has this recently changed with clang-format 3.7? Setting ColumnLimit to 0 stopped working for me and I'm furious, because it worked so well! :D Setting ColumnLimit to 1000 doesn't work either! Is there any other way?

Comment: I've updated the `clang-format` version that `brew` provides so it should now respect `ColumnLimit 0` again. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/9774

Answer (score 2):

My variable ColumnLimit is zero. Method calls are formatted like this:

```
[self presentViewController:scanViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I would like to format them as follows without changing the ColumnLimit variable:

```
[self presentViewController:scanViewController
               animated:YES
             completion:nil];
```

It seems that there is no clang configuration option to achieve this. However, I found a solution that works for me:

If I add // and a line break right after the first parameter (scanViewController here), formatting the code using clang produces the desired result:

```
[self presentViewController:scanViewController //
                   animated:YES
                 completion:nil];
```

This means that the clang formatting puts all parameters on separate lines and aligns the colons.

Comment: I would really love to see an option for this to be on/off without messing with ColumnLimit as well.

Comment: I don't have a specific opinion on this either way, but the one with the columns aligned makes any block inside the call be indented very deep (like colon+indentwidth). I would really like for that to not be the case.

Comment: @StevenHepting, I would really like to have an option to disable this behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue: I wanted to disable colon alignment in methods with block parameters.

Finally I solved it by changing its behavior in `Clang-Format` source code:
I changed `BreakBeforeParamater = true` to `BreakBeforeParameter = false` everywhere in [ContinuationIndenter.cpp](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Format/ContinuationIndenter.cpp) (Thanks to @Matthias for reference to code).

This solution isn't beautiful but works. Now Clang-Format doesn't split ObjC params to new lines.

You can download modified tool from [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i84yz1wbif6sgol/clang-format?dl=0).

PS. Original code was cloned from this repo: http://llvm.org/git/clang.git

Comment: I've now updated the version of `clang-format` that you get with `brew` so it may work again. Let me know.